# Cordova - incorrect scaling on retina displays

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, retina-display

I've just created a fresh Cordova project. I've project using `cordova build` then launched in onto my devices using xcode. Everything works fine, until I launch the application on an iPad Pro 12.9 retina display. Here, the application seems to be somewhat scaled incorrectly, as seen on the following image (notice that even the status bar is scaled incorrectly):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhLAp.jpg:
[image: Incorrect scaling]

I do however, have a way of "resolving" this issue: If I open up xcode and change "Launch Screen File" (under App Icons and Launch Images) to `MainViewController.xib`, it seems to resolve this issue, as seen on the following image. **However** (!) when launch the application, the user is presented with an unwanted black screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7rAX.jpg:
[image: Correct scaling]

**So my question is:** Is there any way of fixing the original issue, without compromising the launch screen? I would very much like a solution that does not involve going into xcode and manually changing something.

**Note:**

- I realize that the issue is not very apparent from the screenshots provided, however, on the device it is quite noticeable.
- I've included the following in my `index.html`-file:

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently Apple is ditching launch screen images in favour of launch storyboard, with the iPad Pro 12.9 being the first candidate to no longer support launch screen images as other devices has. From the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#ios-specific-information):

> Apple is moving away from legacy launch images. There is no official support for providing a native-resolution launch image for the iPad Pro 12.9 or for providing launch images that work with split-screen multitasking or slide-over. If your app doesn't need to support these contexts, then you can continue to use legacy launch images for as long as you like

**However**, luckily Cordova 4.5.1 (and up) does support launch screen storyboards, as described [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#launch-storyboard-images).

To use a story board, I firstly created a [2048x2048 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC7jA.png), named it `Default@3x~universal~anyany.png` and placed it in `res/screen/ios/`. Then i added the following to my `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">
  ···
  <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" />
  ···
</platform>
```